# How do I modify one attribute of a user from the controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, controller

In my app, regular users should be able to click on a button and become super users. In the console,  I can get a user and then do `user.super=true`, `user.save` and it works. I put the code below in my controller, but it flashes the "That didn't work" error instead of successfully changing the user. How do I fix it?

```
def become_super
    user = current_user
    user.super = true
    if user.save
      flash[:success] = "You are super"
    else
      flash[:error] = "That didn't work"
      redirect_to apply_path
    end
```

Comment: it is most probably failing validations.  can you check if there are any errors on `user` inside the else block?

Comment: or you can directly use `if current_user.update_attributes(:super => true)`. But it will again go through the validation check.

Comment: @jvnill, how to I check for errors? I looked at the log, but it just said rollback transaction without explaining why.

Comment: try `user.save!` so it raises an exception but be sure to switch it back after you figure out what's wrong.

Comment: @jvnill, that worked, thanks. Now it says "Validation failed: Password can't be blank, Password is too short...". I do have `validates :password, presence: true..` in the model, but the user already has a password, so I'm not sure why its throwing an error.

Comment: you're probably using some sort encryption so password is only a virtual attribute.  you have to add some if/unless condition to that validation so it doesn't affect operations like these.

Comment: Do you want to allow the users to edit their data without entering the password? then may be you can add `validates :password, presence: true, :on => :create`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you probably have problems with the validations.

You can skip validations altogether (after all you only want to make them super user)

```
current_user.update_attribute(:super, true) # please note, singular!
```

Or you can also let the user know what kind of validation errors ([see ActiveRecord:Error](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActiveRecord/Errors.html)) occur

```
user.super = true
if user.save
  # as before
else 
  flash[:error] = "Please fix your user record first, there are " + 
                  "validation errors: #{user.errors.full_messages.join(", ")}"
  redirect_to apply_path
  # Note: Do not use this pattern for normal CRUD actions!
end
```

Please note, super has a OO meaning and should probably be avoided...